# What is the best way to encrypt in the internet, and decrypt in a private network?

Tags: c#, security, encryption

I have a website, with sensitive information.
And I also have a private network (closed to the internet) that the data in my website is synced into.

I have user accounts that login to the website using a private ID and Password they choose. And I want to be able to know their passwords from the inner network(the closed one).

So I was thinking of using two types of encryption. HASH(1-way) for login and authentication.
And RSA(Public-key) to encrypt the password in my website, and decrypt it with private key in my private network.

I wanted to know if my way is secured enough (or maybe over-secured?) or there is a better option.

And also, what library should I use to encrypt with RSA?

Thanks in advance,
Amir.

Comment: A message digest function or hash function is not a method of encryption.  Also,  this is horribly insecure,  use ssl.

Comment: What I meant with hash is MD5 or SHA-1, and of course I am using SSL, it isn't related. My main question here is how to encrypt the data, so I could i still decrypt the password in the most secured way. knowing that I have an advantage of closed-network not connected to the web. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider` both to encrypt password for your private network and as hash function for authentication. Plaintext password encrypted with public key should be as secure as any other *proper* hash function (e.g. SHA-1), though it will be somewhat longer than typical hash function output.

Comment: So I think you are the first one that got me, SSL isn't related here. The only reason I was thinking using two types of encryption is speed(SHA-1 is faster than RSA) and because I keep my private keep in a private netowrk, my private key cannot be reached from outside. And to do what you suggest, I need to have the private key on my web, (in the internet and not on my private network) which is less secured...

Comment: Unless you have heavy loaded site, you shouldn't notice performance difference between SHA-1 and RSA (although RSA obviously *is* slower).

Comment: Also, you don't have to have private hey on the public website. Public key part (`RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(false)`) will be enough to encrypt password - both during user creation and user authentication. You can perform password validation by comparing encrypted values, not by decrypting stored password.

Comment: Absolutely true, but beware that this is a property of RSA/PKCS1.5, you cannot simply substitute another asymmetric algorithm at a later stage. Note that you need to, encrypt with a public key (with exponent 0x10001) is relatively fast. A good number of iterative hashes with a known salt could be better though.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't devise any proprietary security schemes unless you absolutely have to.  And at the moment there's no such thing as over-secure because any security scheme (including SSL) can be broken.  Proprietary mechanisms are generally considered less-secure but more obscure and often times people who write them feel that security by obscurity gives them protection.  But generally it's the other way around.  Your own obscurity will prevent you from easily identifying security holes, while someone who wants to gain access to your data will have enough experience and knowledge to dissect your security to pieces.

1. If you have a web-based app, you should be unequivocally using SSL between your servers and your users' web browsers. It will protect (as much as it can) all communications between the browser and your web server.  In your scenario, what's stopping someone from simply sniffing out your hash and then using it to log into someone else's account.  If all you check is a hash, and that's all you ask for, they'll just send that in.
2. Once the data gets back to your server, it should be protected just as much as you are protecting it on the public network.  Keep in mind that over 90% of security breaches (no, I do not remember where I get the stat, but I do a lot of reading on this topic) occur from inside your own company.  Disgruntled employees want to do more damage on the way out, or hackers breaking into an internal machine (possibly using social engineering, which is usually the weak point of most companies) first and then discovering that you have no protections inside your own network.
3. Are you absolutely sure you need to store passwords internally? Generally, the only thing you should be storing in your authentication database are password hashes (which should also be pre-seeded to make rainbow table attacks more difficult).  If your database is compromised and hashes are stolen, it would still be very difficult to find out what user name passwords actually are.  Although I don't care how most websites operate, if I find that I'm dealing with a company that has my sensitive information and the password is stored as cleartext, I generally take my business elsewhere.

Comment: The password will be stored as cleatext(or 2-way key based encryption) only in the closed network, in the internet it will be hash. I know nothing is bullet-proof, so this is why I want the best and most secure way to get my solution.

Comment: that's what I was trying to tell you.  Storing passwords in cleartext (or with reversable encryption) is uber insecure.  At a minimum your developers or your admins have access to all the user passwords. Sure you trust everyone today, but what it someone decides to find a different job tomorrow. They can leave with complete access to all user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You must be more descriptive with "I want to be able to know their password"

Reading your question, I would say: If you are using a web form for authentication and it's running over HTTP/HTTPS, I would put a reverse proxy before my WEB server and finish the SSL connections there, reading the HTTP traffic in clear text and storing the password. Note that it has a lot of ethical and privacy related implications.